# KineticJS mouse position of image

Tags: mouseevent, kineticjs

I have a image like this

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            x : x,
            y : y,
            width : 1000,
            height :100,
            image : image,
});
```

How do I get the mouse position based on the image.
according this example, I could get position Object{0, 0} ~ {100, 1000}

I only found an api stage.getPointerPosition()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get mouse position on `click` then you can do this:

```
image.on('click', function(){
    var mousePos = youStage.getPointerPosition();
    var p = { x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y }; // p is a clone of mousePos
    var r =  image.getAbsoluteTransform().copy().invert().point(mousePos);
});
```

Please find the working example below albeit it uses [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io) but the concept is same. And you should also start using Konva cause it's well maintained and documented.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.4.0/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Image Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      var yoda = new Konva.Image({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        width: 106,
        height: 118
      });
      yoda.on('click', function() {
        var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        var p = {
          x: mousePos.x,
          y: mousePos.y
        }; // p is a clone of mousePos
        var r = yoda.getAbsoluteTransform().copy().invert().point(mousePos);
        console.log(r);
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(yoda);
      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9b/Yoda_Empire_Strikes_Back.png/220px-Yoda_Empire_Strikes_Back.png';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I had other way to do this,  using stage.getPointerPosition() + offset(x,y) to calculate the correct position.
I will try the getAbsoluteTransform().copy().invert().point(mousePos); is it the same result.

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994079/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click-event-relative-to-its-layer-in-kineticjs

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is  KonvaJS  the new version of KineticJS?  I will try to move code to KonvaJs,